# Linux boot with usb 3G modem enabled as ttyACM0 device

Tags: linux, usb, driver, boot, modem

im running Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS (desktop), on an embedded device (Odroid U3) and
on boot, my 3G usb modem is seen as a ttyACM0 / ttyACM1 device, which is correct. 
Post boot i am able to simply run wvdial..and from there I can get a connection...

I am running my system headless, and would ideally like to get the OS "converted" to more
of a server configuration(smaller) if possible. I have tried running the 
the ubuntu server version here viewtopic.php?f=77&t=5123, along with
multiple versions of debian(7 / 7.4) but neither will detect the usb modem correctly on boot.

I am a newbie to linux, and the only thing that I have tried is 
trying to force load some of the kernel modules on boot ( /etc/modules ) to try to 
alter the detection of the device on boot. (cdc_acm, usbserial, ppp....etc), no luck.

On the ubuntu server version above I even updated the kernel to
version newer than the one currently on the working desktop version, still no luck,

Does anyone have experience with usb 3G modem detection on boot??, 
Any ideas why it works on the 14.04.1 LTS desktop version , and not any others?, 
thanks a ton...for any suggestions

Comment: After a bit more research,  I think the issue lies with          usb-modeswitch NOT running , or not running correctly at boot time.  Apparently this was fixed in a very recent version of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Appears that there is a patch in 14.04 ubuntu boot that fixes the usb_modeswitch issues.  After taking a raw ubuntu ,  adding usb_modeswitch ,  its now working just fine.
Did not even have to configure usb_modeswitch.